# Search pops a modal window, selecting a result populates several form fields of the parent window

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, modal-dialog

I'm after some guidance on the best way to implement this required functionality in a web page (I'm using MVC 4 and Razor).

1. User types a first name (textbox 1) and a last name (textbox 2) into a form. They then click a 'Search' button (no problem so far).
2. Search queries the database and returns a list of matching customers in a scrolling (may be quite a few results) modal window. The results would be something like first name, last name, address line 1, postcode (i.e easy to fit on one line each). I could easily open a new 'search results' window within the modal but I imagine it'll make step 3 impossible.
3. User chooses one of the results and the full customer & address details: first name, last name, address, town, county, postcode, contact telephone, mobile, email is passed back to the parent form and the modal closes. To obtain the full data set (i.e. the contact details fields) I guess I could either run another search or already have this information within the search results within hidden fields.

   -> name search 
   -> pop modal search results window 
   -> user selects a result 
   -> modal closes 
   -> results populate the corresponding main form fields.

Love to know the most efficient way of doing this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the Javascript Framework du jour.  I'm currently using [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/) and it makes the data-binding scenario you're describing (fairly) trivial.

Comment: AngularJS looks awesome - bit of a learning curve but I will definitely skill-up on this. Thanks. Where do I find more information about 'Javascript Framework du Jour'? I had a google but couldn't locate a specific site. Many thanks again.

Comment: This might be a good place for you to start --> [ToDo MVC](http://todomvc.com/).  This will give you a comparison of what it takes to create a ToDo application utilizing various Javascript frameworks.  Good luck.